# Was the Injustice storyline published in multiple serials? If so, which one do I have?

Tags: dc, suggested-order, injustice

I picked up [Injustice: Volume 1](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/injustice-tom-taylor/1115165832?ean=9781401248437) and [Injustice: Volume 2](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/injustice-tom-taylor/1117057579?ean=9781401250454) recently from Barnes and Noble. I'm looking to pick up Injustice: Volume 3, but it doesn't appear to exist as per my Google searching. Is Injustice published in different formats? If so, which one do I have, and what should I buy to read volume 3 (the chronological continuation of the volumes 1 & 2)?

Volume 2 ended as "End year 1", so I'm thinking that I should pick up "Injustice Year 2 Volume 1", but Volumes 1 & 2 didn't have the "year x" nomenclature, I'm not sure if it's the same publication or a different format. Could someone confirm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the list of current collected editions of the entire Injustice: Gods Among Us series, all five volumes:

> **Year One**
>
> Injustice: Gods Among Us Volume 1 (Collects Issues 1-6)
>
> Injustice: Gods Among Us Volume 2 (Collects Issues 7-12, Annual)
>
> Injustice: Gods Among Us: Year One - The Complete Collection (Collects
>   Entire Series)
>
> **Year Two**
>
> Injustice: Gods Among Us Year Two Volume 1 (Collects Issues 1-6)
>
> Injustice: Gods Among Us Year Two Volume 2 (Collects Issue 7-12,
>   Annual)
>
> **Year Three**
>
> [Injustice: Gods Among Us Year Three Volume 1 (Collects Issues
>   1-7)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401263143)
>
> [Injustice: Gods Among Us Year Three Volume 2 (Collects Issues 8-12,
>   Annual)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401261299)
>
> **Year Four**
>
> [Injustice: Gods Among Us Year Four Volume 1 (Collects Issues 1-7)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401262678)
>
> [Injustice: Gods Among Us Year Four Volume 2 (Collects Issues 8-2,
>   Annual)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401267378)
>
> **Year Five**
>
> [Injustice: Gods Among Us: Year Five Vol. 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401267688)
>
> [Injustice: Gods Among Us: Year Five Vol. 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401268846)
>
> [Injustice: Gods Among Us: Year Five Vol. 3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401272460)

Source: http://injustice.wikia.com/wiki/Injustice:_Gods_Among_Us_Comic .

I took the liberty of adding links to Amazon for years 3, 4 and 5.